# Wordpress caching issue

Tags: cache

I've updated a page in wordpress and can see the correct result in "preview mode", but if I view the page outside of the admin interface the update does not show.

I've search around and tried the following, of which nothing worked:

- Disable or clear wordpress cache plugins, of which I have non installed
- Checked the wp-config.php file for anything referencing to cache
- Cleared browser cache, and tried multiple browsers
- Checked .htaccess file for any apache modules to do with caching

Now I'm stumped and don't know where else to look.

Comment: Is the page live and you can provide link to it? Had you tried switching to default theme?

Comment: The website is live, and the page is published. I can't provide a link, since this is an password-protected page.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

Had two pages with the same content, and slightly different names, and I was updating the other one.